# Count is not Captured in Shell Script Variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix, sh

I am trying to capture the number of active processes by running a command and trying to capture the result in a variable of shell script, but unfortunately, nothing is getting captured. The code is as below:

```
#!/bin/ksh

## Checking whether or not the Previous Build is Completed

count_build_status=`ps -ef | grep BDD_PreCheck.sh | grep -c FT_BGmgmt` | tee -a ${logFile}

    echo "The Value of Count Build Status is $count_build_status"

        if [[ "${count_build_status}" != "0" ]]

        then

            echo INFO -  The previous build has not ended yet. Please Wait for some time or contact the Administrator | tee -a $logFile

        exit 1;

        fi

exit 0;
```

Here, `ps -ef | grep BDD_PreCheck.sh | grep -c FT_BGmgmt` gives result as 0 if executed individually, but the value stored in 'count_build_status' is null.

Can anyone help?

Comment: bash is not ksh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is backtick, which does not assign value to the variable when tee'ing is not done inside backtick. It should be included at the end of logFile as in the code below.

```
#!/bin/bash

logFile=log.txt

## Checking whether or not the Previous Build is Completed

count_build_status=`ps -ef | grep BDD_PreCheck.sh | grep -c FT_BGmgmt | tee -a ${logFile}`

    echo "The Value of Count Build Status is $count_build_status"

        if [[ "${count_build_status}" != "0" ]]

        then

            echo INFO -  The previous build has not ended yet. Please Wait for some time or contact the Administrator | tee -a $logFile

        exit 1;

        fi

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

example: capture output of a cmd-line to a variable and append a logfile with tee:

```
var=`ps -ef | grep 0 | grep -c 1 | tee -a log`
echo $var
```